# Get StackPanel Coordinates wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a stack panel and I want to open a new window **above** the stack panel.
I use dialog manager to show the new window when mouse click on stack panel and I want it to appear above the stack panel.
How can I get the Stack Panel coordinates and pass them to the ViewModel?
**I work with MVVM so no code behind..**

```
            <StackPanel x:Name="TotalDefectsSP" Style="{StaticResource InfoStackStyle}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility="Visible">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LeftMouseButtonDown}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Mouse.Get}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <TextBlock Text="{localization:Translate}" localization:Translate.Uid="Total Defects:"/>
                <TextBlock  Margin="0,0,5,0" >
```

Comment: "*I work with MVVM so no code behind*" - this is a big misconception. MVVM does not forbid to have code behind. Just take care that the view model does not know the view.

Comment: You can pass the default `Point` value (`0,0`) to the `PointToScreen()` method to find the screen-relative coordinates of any UI element. Then you can use those screen coordinates to position your new window. See duplicates.

Comment: @Clemens I will remember that. Thanks. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho forgive my ignorance but how do I do that?

Comment: There are examples in each of the duplicate questions. I recommend you take a look.